# Dynamically loading component using import or fetch

Tags: svelte

Is there a way to import components in svelte dynamically using fetch or import? May be a svelte file or module file created from shareable component (still don't know how that works). very new with svelte and very excited.

I found some code in stackoverflow, which worked for v2. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50300176/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-load-a-svelte-template-at-runtime)

```html
<button on:click="loadChatbox()">
  chat to a customer service representative
</button>

{#if ChatBox}
  <svelte:component this={ChatBox}/>
{/if}

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      async loadChatbox() {
        const { default: Chatbox } = await import('./Chatbox.html');
        this.set({ Chatbox });
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The same functionality exists in Svelte 3, but you only need to assign the dynamically imported component to a regular variable that you use for the `this` property on the `svelte:component`.

**Example ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/18fd54f036fb4f24b7abfd94d4940583?version=3.4.4))**

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
  let Chatbox;

  function loadChatbox() {
    import('./ChatBox.svelte').then(res => Chatbox = res.default)
  }
</script>

<button on:click="{loadChatbox}">Load chatbox</button>
<svelte:component this="{Chatbox}" />

<!-- ChatBox.svelte -->
<h1>Dynamically loaded chatbox</h1>
<input />
```

Comment: Great, this works. I tried it in the repl and it works as it suppose to but the rollup build fails while doing locally using the sveltejs/template. With the help of this I was also able to load external mjs in runtime to load components. Here are the related project [main project](https://github.com/ssuwal/svelte-gettting-statrted), [component generator](https://github.com/ssuwal/svelte-component-generator) and [module server](https://github.com/ssuwal/svelte-test-component-server). I had to switch to mjs since import didn't like svelte or html served from server.

Comment: What do you have to do to get rollup to put the components in the build output?

Comment: @AndrewMao inlineDynamicImports