# Unable to dynamically load a component

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to import a component:

```
 import('./components/'+componentName+'.svelte')
   .then(res => {src = res.default })
```

but compiler issues an error:

```
Loading module from “http://localhost...” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)
```

How I can allow this MIME type?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56431848/dynamically-loading-component-using-import-or-fetch

Comment: I've saw it before, but I have the issue with MIME.

Comment: Have you seen the comment below the question: "I had to switch to mjs since import didn't like svelte or html served from server."

Comment: Ah, thank you. jsm, etc - never mind that gathering already created files is such a difficult thing

Comment: Svelte components should be served as JS, not HTML... Are you sure the component you're importing is compiled? What's your bundler and config?

Comment: @rixo :  I'm using rollup as bundler. Config as follow:
output: {
  sourcemap: true,
  format: 'iife',
  name: 'app',
  file: 'public/bundle.js'
 },
 plugins: [
  svelte({
   dev: !production
  }),
  resolve({
   extensions: ['.svelte', '.js']
  })