# Svelte : Importing component dynamically is not working

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'd like to insert component dynamically. But, it fails. Could you someone please tell me about it and advice to solve this?
[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/91134bfe5b6841b9b5e7f80f2747a41f?version=3.31.0) is here.

```
<script>
let Chatbox;
function loadChatbox() {
    // this is available.
    // import('./ChatBox.svelte').then(res => Chatbox = res.default)
    // but, this is not. Why?? and How to make it??
    const name = './ChatBox.svelte';
    import(name).then(res => Chatbox = res.default)
}
</script>
<button on:click="{loadChatbox}">Load chatbox</button>
<svelte:component this="{Chatbox}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to separate the component path? I believe if you just change your code to this it would work.

```
import('./ChatBox.svelte').then(res => Chatbox = res.default)
```

see [Dynamically loading component using import or fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56431848/dynamically-loading-component-using-import-or-fetch)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my code. I need to use a variable to import dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "await":

```
<script>
let Chatbox;
async function loadChatbox() { // need to make this an async function too
    // this is available.
    // import('./ChatBox.svelte').then(res => Chatbox = res.default)
    // but, this is not. Why?? and How to make it??
    const name = './ChatBox.svelte';
    (await import(name)).then(res => Chatbox = res.default) // added await
}
</script>
<button on:click="{loadChatbox}">Load chatbox</button>
<svelte:component this="{Chatbox}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36530495/14858601

```
// index.js
export { default as Template1 } from './Template1';
export { default as Template2 } from './Template2';


// OtherComponent.js
import * as templates from './index.js'
...
// handy to be able to fall back to a default!
return templates[name] || templates.Template1;
```