# How to use bindings inside raw html?

Tags: javascript, binding, svelte

How can one use dynamic attributes and bindings while rendering raw html. Suppose:

```
<script>
let name = 'Joseph'
let test = '<p>{name}</p>'
</script>

{@html test} <!-- Outputs: {name} instead of Joseph -->
```

I know, one would answer that, a better approach to this would be creating a component. But still I want to ask, if there is a way of using bindings inside raw html rendering?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50300176/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-load-a-svelte-template-at-runtime. Or you can do something like this:
<script>
let name = 'Joseph';
let test ; 
$: test = '<p >' +  name + '</p>'
</script>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. But you can do this: `` {@html `<p>${name}</p>`} ``